# Prove function f is integrable on [a,b] using the riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:**

> Show that the function defined by  $$f(x) = \begin{cases}b, & \text{if } x=a, \\ a, & \text{if } a < x ≤ b.\end{cases}$$ is Riemann integrable.

**Attempt:**

I made a sketch of the function to make it visible and easier, however I'm struggling to find the partition, is the change in $x$ just simply $(b-a)$ or is it $\frac{(b-a)}{n}$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990559/is-this-riemann-integrable/1990637#1990637

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For every $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $a < a + \varepsilon < b$ we have $\displaystyle \bar \int_{a}^{a+\varepsilon} f \leq b \cdot \varepsilon$. Then, for any of these $\varepsilon > 0$

$$a\cdot (b-a) \leq \bar \int_a^b f = \bar\int_a^{a+\varepsilon} f + \bar \int_{a+\varepsilon}^b \leq b \cdot \varepsilon + a \cdot (b-a-\varepsilon) = a \cdot (b-a) + (b-a)\cdot \varepsilon$$ Thus, it must be $$\bar \int_a^b f(x)dx = a\cdot (b-a)$$

Now you need to find $\displaystyle\underline \int_{a}^b f$, which is easy to see that is $a \cdot (b-a)$.

Comment: Excuse my formatting, I approached the problem a diffferent way. Firstly i noted partition P={x_0,x_1,..,x_n} with I=b-a, since f(x)=a when a<x≤b M_k=sup f=a, m_k=inf f=a when k=2,...,n. // the first interval I_1=[a,x_1] where a<x_1≤b. so M_1=b & m_1=a. Since f(a)=b & f(x)=a for a<x≤b it follows U(f,P)=x_1 and L(f,P)=a. so I_m= sup L(f,P)=a and I_M=inf {x_1: a<x_1≤b}= a hence as I_M=I_m it is integrable. is this correct

Comment: You need to learn how to use MathJax. Here is a [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to get yourself started.

Comment: I approached the problem a diffferent way. Firstly i noted partition $P$={$x_0,x_1,..,x_n$} with $\delta$$x$=$(b-a)$, since $f(x)=a$ when $a<x≤b$ $M_k=sup(f)=a$, $m_k=inf f=a$ when $k=2,...,n.$ // the first interval $I_1=[a,x_1]$ where $a<x_1≤b$. so $M_1=b$ & $m_1=a$. Since $f(a)=b$ & $f(x)=a$ for $a<x≤b$ it follows $U(f,P)=x_1$ and $L(f,P)=a$. so $I_m= sup L(f,P)=a$ and $I_M=inf {x_1: a<x_1≤b}= a$ hence as $I_M=I_m$ it is integrable. is this correc, sorry for any inconvience I missed the $ signs.

Comment: If you want an answer to whether your approach is correct, then that should be part of the question, not part of a comment in response to someone's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A function is Riemann integrable if for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(P,f) - L(P,f) \lt \epsilon. $

So, let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. Choose $n$ such that $n \gt \frac{(b-a)^2}{\epsilon}$. Let $P = \{a = x_0 \lt x_1 \lt ... \lt x_n = b\}$ be such that $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_{i-1} = \frac{b-a}{n} \lt \frac {b-a}{\frac{(b-a)^2}{\epsilon}} = \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}.$ Put $M_i = $sup $\{f(x) : x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i\}$ and $m_i = $inf$ \{f(x) : x_{i-1} \le x \le x_i\}$.

Then we have $U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} M_i \Delta x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} m_i \Delta x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta x_i (M_i - m_i)$, and since $M_i = m_i = a$ for $i = 2, 3, ..., n$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Delta x_i (M_i - m_i) \lt \epsilon $. This completes the proof.

Comment: Excuse my formatting, I approached the problem a diffferent way. Firstly i noted partition P={x_0,x_1,..,x_n} with I=b-a, since f(x)=a when a<x≤b M_k=sup f=a, m_k=inf f=a when k=2,...,n. // the first interval I_1=[a,x_1] where a<x_1≤b. so M_1=b & m_1=a. Since f(a)=b & f(x)=a for a<x≤b it follows U(f,P)=x_1 and L(f,P)=a. so I_m= sup L(f,P)=a and I_M=inf {x_1: a<x_1≤b}= a hence as I_M=I_m it is integrable. is this correct

Comment: honestly learn to format this is unreadable

Comment: I approached the problem a diffferent way. Firstly i noted partition $P$={$x_0,x_1,..,x_n$} with $\delta$$x$=$(b-a)$, since $f(x)=a$ when $a<x≤b$ $M_k=sup(f)=a$, $m_k=inf f=a$ when $k=2,...,n.$ // the first interval $I_1=[a,x_1]$ where $a<x_1≤b$. so $M_1=b$ & $m_1=a$. Since $f(a)=b$ & $f(x)=a$ for $a<x≤b$ it follows $U(f,P)=x_1$ and $L(f,P)=a$. so $I_m= sup L(f,P)=a$ and $I_M=inf {x_1: a<x_1≤b}= a$ hence as $I_M=I_m$ it is integrable. is this correc, sorry for any inconvience I missed the $ signs.