# Riemann Integral definition problem.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

My Question is:

Let $a$, $b \in\mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. Define $f \colon [a, b] \to\mathbb{R}$ by
$f(x) =\left\{
\begin{array}{c l} 
     b  &\mbox{ if} &x=a \\
     a & \mbox{ if}&a<x≤ b.
\end{array}\right.$

Use the definition of the Riemann integral to prove that $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ and
determine the value of the integral $\int_{a}^{b} f$

I know you have to split this up into n-sub intervals but i cant really grasp the concept for this question. Any help towards the answer will be appreciated.

Comment: See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000973/prove-function-f-is-integrable-on-a-b-using-the-riemann-integral/2001010#2001010) anwers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Split the interval into two subintervals
$$[a,b]=\Bigl[a, a+\frac1n\Bigr]\cup\Bigl[a+\frac1n,b\Bigr]$$
then use *Chasles' relation*.

Comment: I've not come across this before. Is there another way to look at it??